# Test multiple constraint violation return messages

Tags: testng, hibernate-validator

I am testing that my hibernate size constraints for specific Strings, and I'd like to check all the return codes in one unit test method instead of having to make a separate function to test each size constraint error return. 
So I have some strings in my java class that look like:

```
@Size(max = 10, message = "String a is too big")
private String a;

@Size(max = 20, message = "String b is too big")
private String b;
```

And in my test class I am currently testing them like this:

```
@Test
public void aIsTooLongTest(){
    ...code to set length of a as a string > 10 and b < 20
    Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeObj>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(instanceOfSomeObj);
    assertEquals(2, constraintViolations.size());
    assertEquals("String a is too big", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
}
```

This works fine, but when I make the tests like this, I have to write 2 separate methods (one for the case when a is too big and one for when b is too big). I want to combine this to one method where a and b are too big and I want to check that the correct error messages are getting returned for both. The issue is, I can't seem to find a way to access specific error return messages. For instance, the code

```
constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage()
```

doesn't get the error return messages in any specific order.
Is there a way I can avoid this problem and have one method to test the error codes, or must I split up each case into a separate method?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe there's a way to store the message in a map somehow, and then access them for the assertEquals

Answer (score 2):

The order of the returned constraint violations is undefined. So you can't rely on it.

You might want to take a look at our test utils (they use assertj but you can do without it):
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/test-utils/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/testutil/ConstraintViolationAssert.java

Comment: You also may consider to use AssertJ directly: `assertThat( constraintViolations ).extracting( "message" ).containsOnly( "message 1", "message 2" );` `containsOnly()` accepts any order of the given elements.